# What are the chances to drop the Boon of the Hoarder gem?

Tags: diablo-iii

Apparently there is a legendary gem that can only be dropped by Greed in the Treasure Realm: the [Boon of the Hoarder](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Boon_of_the_Hoarder).  Any idea about this gem's drop chance ?

Comment: I think 100 percent if you don't have it yet.

Comment: Wait what ?  Really ?!

Comment: I've had it drop 2/2 times I entered the realm. (with different characters) and if it is in your shared stash, it counts as owned, or that's how it works for the other legendary gems anyway.

Comment: @Arperum thats been patched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has 100% drop rate if you don't have it. You just have to enter the Vault and kill Greed.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this gem in a grift on patch day 3 days ago. I was not aware it would drop so. I thought I'd have to find that treasure goblin but.. it dropped at the end by the rift guardian.